# Intellij Idea - compiling Typescript to Javascript and keeping directory structure

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, typescript

I'm trying to get Intellij Idea to keep the directory structure when compiling Typescript to Javascript. My directory structure is as follows:

```
root
- ts
  - SomeClass1.ts
  - SomeFolder
    - AwesomeClass2.ts
- tsc
```

I want the resulting compiled files to be:

```
root
- tsc
  - SomeClass1.js
  - SomeFolder
    - AwesomeClass2.js
```

[image: How I want it to look like]

This is my Typescript configuration:

[image: Typescript configuration]

[image: Typescript installation]

However when trying to compile, I'm getting this error in the console:

[image: Typescript compilation error]

- If I set "Use output path" to "tsc", it works, but the directory structure is gone and that leads to RequireJS to not find the files anymore.
- If I set "Use output path" to "tsc\$FileDirRelativeToSourcepath$", I get the "cannot read the property 'replace' of undefined".
- If I disable "Use output path" and use "--outDir" with "Command line options", the files do compile into the right directory, but IntelliJ no longer recompiles files automatically if they've been changed.

## UPDATE, solution by Nitzan Tomer:

Create tsconfig.json in the root directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "tsc",
    "rootDir": "ts",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "tsc"
  ]
}
```

and enable "use tsconfig.json" in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `tsconfig.json` you can specify the `rootDir` and `outDir`, if you do that then it will keep the directory structure of the `rootDir` in the compiled version inside the `outDir`.

In your case:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "tsc",
        "rootDir": "ts",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true
    }
}
```

Place this file as `tsconfig.json` in your `root` directory and in intellij/webstorm `Enable Typescript Compiler` and then `Use tsconfig.json`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I did add an exclude directive, because it was trying to compile the files in "tsc". I'll update my original question with the tsconfig.json.